# WordPress Text Editor not showing html

Tags: html, wordpress

I've recently taken over a website from my colleague to manage, I used to use the html Text editor to update my page, but I'm not sure what he's done, the text editor is not showing any html codes, it does have part of the content but they're pure texts not html. Where can I change the setting in order to retain access to html text in word press?

I've tried deactivating all plugin (except UpDraftPlus Backup), but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the admin area, and the problem you're experiencing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the `wp-config.php` file. You can hide some options from the WordPress editor, using:

```
define( 'DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', true );
```

Also, try to test in another theme. A simple script in `functions.php` fixes that.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_editor/

Comment: where can i find the php file? I think this might be the case as the blog inherits a theme that we bought by a paid designer.

Comment: found the php files and this answered my problem, phps can be found under apperance>editors>templates

Comment: Leo, can I further the question of how to edit the phps? it's write now read only.

Comment: @ChunfaatJonathanNgai the easiest way is using a FTP Software or a SSH to access the server. The WordPress Editor is for emergency, avoid use it as best practices, ok?

If you don't have access to the FTP, talk to your host server provider.

Comment: Thank you man! I was searching for the solution from last 3 days, finally got the solution. Works like a charm. :) Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

Go to your User Profile under Dashboard > Users.

Make sure that  "Disable the visual editor when writing" is not checked

Comment: it's not check, the visual editor is fine, it's the html code under the text tab is not showing. i think it's filtered by the blog designer to make it more user friendly.

Comment: Sounds like wpautop was disable on the sites  your previous worked on.
Just google "wpautop" :-)

Comment: Thank you : ) if it will be possible i give you more than one up vote

Answer (score 1):

You can also replace the HTML code by:

```
< = &lt; or &#60;
> = &gt; or &#62;
/ = &#47;   
] = &#93;
[ = &#91;
" = &quot; or &#34;
' = &#39;
“ = &ldquo; or &#8220;
” = &rdquo; or &#8220;
‘ = &lsquo; or &#8216;
’ = &rsquo; or &#8217;
& = &amp; or &#38;
```

So instead of

```
<div>
```

use

```
&ltdiv&gt
```

It works great for me

For more detail check this [link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_Code_in_Your_Posts)

Answer (score 0):

Find file wp-config.php at wordpress, 
 `define( 'DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', true )`; comments or delete this code.

`define( 'DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', true );` this will help for security so once your work done please uncomment or write at wp-config.php

This file is located in the root of your WordPress file directory and contains your website's base configuration details, such as database connection information.

**Disable the Plugin and Theme Editor**

Occasionally you may wish to disable the plugin or theme editor to prevent *overzealous users from being able to edit sensitive files and potentially crash the site*. **Disabling these also provides an additional layer of security if a hacker gains access to a well-privileged user account.**

```
define( 'DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', true );
```

Please note: the functionality of some plugins may be affected by the use of

```
current_user_can('edit_plugins')
```

in their code. Plugin authors should avoid checking for this capability, or at least check if this constant is set and display an appropriate error message. Be aware that if a plugin is not working this may be the cause.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was wp_post Auto Increment value which was unset due to database import.

```
    SELECT `AUTO_INCREMENT`
    FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'Database'
    AND   TABLE_NAME   = 'wp_post';

    ALTER TABLE wp_posts AUTO_INCREMENT=101
```